# How to define alias to url in webpack config similarly to vite

Tags: javascript, webpack, config, alias, vite

using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) to generate a VueJs project `npm init vue@latest`I get the following alias in the configuration file `vite.config.js`:

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
}
```

Replacing the upper chunck of code in `webpack v5` (for another project):

```js
const { fileURLToPath, URL } = require("url")
resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
}
```

yields the following error:

```bash
'@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module
```

Can you please tell me how can I replace the aliasing correctly in `webpack v5`? thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the `fileURLToPath`, but in the `docs`, they are using `path.resolve`

```
const path = require('path');
resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components')
    }
}
```

[WEBPACK](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias)

Comment: it didn't resolve the path: `ERROR in ./src/App.vue Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/assets/logo.svg'` because the path in the `App.vue` is **relative**, not absolute!

Comment: Is '@' alias for 'src' folder? Are assets inside the src folder?

Comment: `'@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src)` has worked in my case, thanks.